# "Year of plantation" or "plantation year"

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to use *year of plantantion* to refer to the year that a vineyard was planted?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It sounds far more natural to my ears, and seems far more common on Google. Not that there is anything basically wrong with 'plantation year'.

Comment: Google search results for "year of planting" seem to be about grapes and vineyards, "year of plantation" not so much.

Comment: Although most people would understand what 'plantation year' is supposed to mean, I think you should go with `year of plantation/planting`. When in comes to time, `of` constructs seem to be more common. Date of birth; time of death; month of joining... and so on

Answer (score 2):

The word plantation is more often used to mean something like "an estate on which crops are grown" or "colonization or settlement of emigrants" than "the act or event of planting". As a native English speaker living in Ireland I have never heard it used to mean "the act of planting" but it is there in some dictionaries.

Google search results for "year of planting" seem to be about grapes and vineyards. Search results for "year of plantation" seem less so. This suggests "year of planting" would be a better choice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is correct in his understanding. "Year of plantation" is also widely used by the vineyards themselves.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth I have amended my answer. I should have checked more dictionaries.

Comment: @JulieCarter I don't doubt what you say, my point is that "year of planting" seems to be more widely used, especially to mean "the year that a vineyard was planted"

Comment: @JulieCarter surely you mean by the vintners, not the vineyards.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be [First] Year of Planting.  Here is a page from a nursery supply company. In the next-to-last paragraph it refers to a "successful first year planting".

http://www.vintagenurseries.com/f/terms-conditions/replacement.html

In America, the word  "plantation" evokes images of large cotton or tobacco farms in the antebellum South.  I don't see it used to refer to the act of planting.

Comment: But Collins does.

Comment: And that proves? [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Thirteenth+of+September%2Cyear+of+planting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyear%20of%20planting%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: Your 'Y' was capital. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=year+of+plantation%2Cyear+of+planting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyear%20of%20plantation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyear%20of%20planting%3B%2Cc0)